# Hibernate fetching deleted java enum types from db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, enums

I have an Enum class which has some values.
We've decided to remove one of these values and its all implementation from the code.
We dont want to delete any records from DB.
My Enum class is something like this:

```
public enum CourseType {

   VIDEO("CourseType.VIDEO"),
   PDF("CourseType.PDF"), 
   QUIZ("CourseType.QUIZ"),      
   SURVEY("CourseType.SURVEY"),
   POWERPOINT("CourseType.POWERPOINT")  //*this one will be removed*
   ...
}
```

My Course Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CRS")
public class Course {

    @Column(name = "COURSE_TYPE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CourseType courseType;

    @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
    private String author;

    ....

     @Override
    public CourseType getCourseType() {
        return courseType;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCourseType(CourseType courseType) {
        this.courseType = courseType;
    }

    ....
}
```

After I removed the *Powerpoint* type from the Java Class and tried to fetch some values from the DB,
I get a mapping error for the removed type.

I have a code like this:

```
Course course = courseService.get(id);
```

If I gave a course id which its type is 'POWERPOINT' in the database,
the method gets the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [POWERPOINT]
>   for enum class [com.tst.enums.CourseType]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.fromName(EnumType.java:461)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:449)
>     at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:107)   at
>   org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:127)    at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)    at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2912)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1673)

Is there any way when I try to retrieve a query result from DB,
hibernate will not fetch if that records' course_type column doesn't match with the any of the enum values in the code?
Do I have to use some kind of filter?

Comment: So in your select query, you should exclude rows with the deleted `enum` value.

Comment: Thanks, but 'courseService.get(id);' is not a query, it's a generic method. Besides, I don't want to write exclude row code everywhere in the code.

Comment: You will probably have to write your own query if you want to exclude an ENUM. After all, Enums are sort of made so that a value *has* to match with what is inside the enum.

Comment: So what value *do* you expect the `courseType` attribute to have in that case? Your question is a bit confusing, because you first mentioned calling `get`, then you talk about a "query result" and then in the comments you say it's not about a query, but about `get`. If you don't want a particular row to be returned by the `get` method, you should remove it from the table. It's not clear why you don't want to do that.

Comment: @Codeer you're not clearing up any confusion here, you're adding to it. It is the OP who claims in his question that there is a query result, but then in his comment says that it's not a query. The OP should clarify what they want and why they don't want the most obvious solution (delete the records with courses of types that no longer exist from the database (and archive them somewhere, if needed))

Comment: You need to use the `@Filter` annotation.  Try a Google search for "jpa hibernate entity filter" or here is a link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use filters,
something like the following should work:

1. Add POWERPOINT back into the enum.
2. Add a deleted flag to the POWERPOINT enum value.
3. After the course list is loaded, remove courses that have a deleted courseType value.

New CourseType enum:

```c#
public enum CourseType
{
    VIDEO("CourseType.VIDEO", false),
    POWERPOINT("CourseType.POWERPOINT", true);

    private boolean deletedFlag;

    public CourseType(         
        existingParameter, // do whatever you are currently doing with this parameter
        deletedFlagValue)
    {
        // code to handle existing parameter
        deletedFlag = deletedFlagValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use annotation @filter

```
@Filter(name = "myFilter", condition = "courseType <> 'CourseType.POWERPOINT'")
```

and enable it

```
session.enableFilter("myFilter")
```